# Missing props validation - Component and pageProps in _app.js. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

The following is the code used in _app.js for the nextjs project with typescript

```
import React from 'react'
import '../styles/globals.css'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

The error says

4:18  Error: 'Component' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
4:29  Error: 'pageProps' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempts, I found that importing AppProps would solve this.

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { AppProps } from "next/app";

export default function App({Component, pageProps}:AppProps) {
   return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have `prop-types` npm package installed, you can try this:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/globals.css';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

MyApp.propTypes = {
  pageProps: PropTypes.object,
  Component: PropTypes.element
};

export default MyApp;
```